# Two Algorithm A and B solve the same problem

Tags: algorithms

Two algorithms $A$ and $B$ solve the same problem.  $A$ solves a problem of size $n$ with $n^2~2^n$ operations. $B$ solves it with $n!$ operations. As $n$ grows, which algorithm uses fewer operations?

Comment: Hi & welcome! Firstly, please try to use $\LaTeX$ to write mathematics in future - for example, I don't know what "n22n" means, mathematically. Secondly, you should tell us what you do know, and any thoughts you've had about the problem.

Comment: Is it $n^² 2^n$ by any chance?

Comment: thank you, sorry for that but yes thats what it means. and i have no idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is your friend.